# NPE thrown when starting new Activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity, fragment

I have the following code which is merely a husk of a UI for my app. It loads successfuly, but when the "Create Plot" button is pressed in the MainActivity - which should launch the CreatePlotActivity - the app crashes without starting the next activity. Instead, an NPE gets thrown. Here are all the relevant files. Note: line 33 of CreateOptionsFragment is `list.setAdapter(adapter)`:

LogCat

```
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.probaddieweaponplotter/com.example.probaddieweaponplotter.CreatePlotActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at com.example.probaddieweaponplotter.PlotOptionsListFragment.onActivityCreated(PlotOptionsListFragment.java:33)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1703)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1840)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5107)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-02 02:33:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13555):    ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.probaddieweaponplotter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_create_plot);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreatePlotActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

CreatePlotActivity.java

```
package com.example.probaddieweaponplotter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CreatePlotActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_plot);      
    }
}
```

PlotOptionsListFragment.java

```
package com.example.probaddieweaponplotter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlotOptionsListFragment extends Fragment { 

    ListView listView;  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plot_options_list,
                container, false);


    }   

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.plot_options_listView);       
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);           
    }

}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<PlotOptionsListItem> list;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        list = new ArrayList<PlotOptionsListItem>();

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        String[] items = res.getStringArray(R.array.plot_options_list_items);
        String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.plot_options_list_descriptions);

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            list.add(new PlotOptionsListItem(items[i], descriptions[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plot_options_list_single_item, parent, false);
        TextView item = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.plot_options_list_item_text);
        TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.plot_options_list_desc_text);

        PlotOptionsListItem temp = list.get(position);

        item.setText(temp.getItem());
        description.setText(temp.getDescription());

        return row;
    }

}

class PlotOptionsListItem {

    private String item;
    private String description;

    public PlotOptionsListItem(String item, String description) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.setItem(item);
        this.setDescription(description);
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
           android:contentDescription="@string/activity_main_cover_image_desc"
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"       
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main_button_layout"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_create_plot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_half"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/button_create_plot" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_view_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_create_plot"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/button_view_gallery" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_help_faq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_view_gallery"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/button_help_faq" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_advanced_settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_help_faq"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/button_advanced_settings" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_create_plot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_plot_options_list"
        android:name="com.example.probaddieweaponplotter.PlotOptionsListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_generate_plot_button"
        android:name="com.example.probaddieweaponplotter.GeneratePlotButtonFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_plot_options_detail" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_plot_options_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/plot_options_listView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >          
</ListView>
```

plot_options_list_single_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plot_options_list_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plot_options_list_desc_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plot_options_list_item_text"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.probaddieweaponplotter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.probaddieweaponplotter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.probaddieweaponplotter.CreatePlotActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_plot"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.probaddieweaponplotter.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.probaddieweaponplotter.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Care to share why this was downvoted? Can you point me to the duplicate, if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plot_options_list,
            container, false);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.plot_options_listView);     
    return v;


}   

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` belongs to the Fragment layout. So use `getView()` in `onActivityCreated` to initialize `ListView`

You would use `getActivity()` to initialize views of Activity in Fragment and that is not what you want.

Change this

```
listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.plot_options_listView);
```

to

```
listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.plot_options_listView);
```

Comment: Your reasoning sounds valid to me, but for some reason this didn't remedy the issue.

Comment: @NickBroderick Look at `public View getView ()

Added in API level 11
Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.

Returns
The fragment's root view, or null if it has no layout.`

Comment: @NickBroderick its not the problem with `getView()` something else that you are missing

Comment: Yes, and I found the issue: my `onCreateView()` returns the very `ListView` I am trying to use! (The `ListView` I need is the root of `fragment_plot_options_list.xml`.) Therefore, the correct line is simply `listView = (ListView) getView();` Apparently, `findViewById` cannot recognize when the view to be found is right under its nose.

Comment: @NickBroderick that's because that is the root view and there are no child views

Answer (score 0):

Just thought you should know the reason:

The layout of your fragment in which you have your `listview` is `R.layout.fragment_plot_options_list`.

Where you need to `findViewById` is from the `fragment_plot_options_list.xml` before returning the inflated layout:

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plot_options_list,
                container, false);
```

When you call

```
 listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.plot_options_listView);
```

in `onActivityCreated`, its like calling the same in an activity without a call to `setContentView()` so you get the NPE.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately, this deserves an upvote that I can't currently give.